# Why is the text in my navigation bar not aligned and how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navigationbar

You can see that the icon and "sign in" link isn't straight. How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22UTF-8%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv=%22X-UA-Compatible%22%20content=%22IE=edge%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22wi$*$dth=device-wi$*$dth,%20initial-scale=1.0%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22styles.css%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EGoogle%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3C/head%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22right%20button%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3ESign%20In%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22right%22%3E%3Cspan%20class=%22material-icons%20navigation%20icon%22%20%3Eapps%3C/span%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22right%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3EImages%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22right%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3EGmail%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22left%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3EAbout%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22left%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%3EStore%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A&css=*%20%7B%0A%20%20margin:%200;%0A%20%20padding:%200;%0A%20%20font-size:%2012px;%0A%20%20font-family:%20arial,%20sans-serif;%0A%7D%0A%0Ali%20%7B%0A%20%20float:%20right;%0A%20%20list-style-type:%20none;%0A%20%20margin-top:%2020px;%0A%7D%0A%0Aa%20%7B%0A%20%20text-decoration:%20none;%0A%20%20color:%20black;%0A%7D%0A%0A.left%20%7B%0A%20%20float:%20left;%0A%7D%0A%0A.left%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20margin-left:%2020px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.right%20%7B%0A%20%20margin-right:%2020px;%0A%7D%0A%0A.button%20%7B%0A%20%20background-color:%20#4485f4;%0A%20%20padding:%207px;%0A%20%20border-radius:%205%25;%0A%7D%0A%0A.button%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%7D%0A%0A.icon%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20grey;%0A%7D%0A%0Aa%20%7B%0A%20%20justify-items:%20center;%0A%7D%0A&js=

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you can write this in your ul selector:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

But in this case, rearrange your html code and write them in the order the options are going to be on your navbar.

```
<ul>
    <li class="left"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
    <li class="right"><span class="material-icons navigation icon">apps</span</li>
    <li class="right button"><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another way is to do that is to use line-height in ul.

```
ul {
    line-height:  20px;
}
```

Although it is not always perfect.

Comment: Thank you. Though the first method aligned the button and text, another problem occurred where the text that used to be on the left side is now on the right side collided with the rest of the texts.